# How to resolve problem with a warning of dotnet new "Failed to scan..."?

Tags: .net, templating

I am learning [how to create an item template for dotnet new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/cli-templates-create-item-template). After some exercises, I cannot resolve a warning (look at line 3):

```
PS C:\Users\abrakadabra\repos\magic\templates> dotnet new install .\magic.templates.builders.id\
The following template packages will be installed:
   C:\Users\abrakadabra\repos\magic\templates\magic.templates.builders.id\

Warning: Failed to scan C:\Users\abrakadabra\repos\parent_folder\working\templates\MyProject.Con.
Details: Template package location C:\Users\abrakadabra\repos\parent_folder\working\templates\MyProject.Con is not supported, or doesn't exist.
Success: C:\Users\abrakadabra\repos\magic\templates\magic.templates.builders.id\installed the following templates:
Template Name               Short Name      Language  Tags
--------------------------  --------------  --------  ----------------------
Magic ID Builder            mgctestbuildid  [C#]      Common/Code/Magic
```

What to do in that case?

Answer (score 4):

Because I was following the tutorial, I was using some mentioned example folders, like `parent_folder` and `working`. After the exercises, I removed these folders. But `dotnet new` was looking for them when I tried installing the next new templates.

You can use `dotnet new uninstall` to list all the paths for local templates which can be removed and then fix or remove the paths.

When I remove the mentioned one, the warning disappeared. In my example I executed:

```
dotnet new uninstall 'C:\Users\abrakadabra\repos\parent_folder\working\templates\MyProject.Con'
```